# stubborn loop in clojure, let not getting evaluated

Tags: loops, clojure

I have the following code:

```
(do
  (prn "sleeping for 60 seconds")
  (Thread/sleep 6000)
  (prn "kicking off calendar downloads @ " (new java.util.Date))
  (let [links (map #(clojure.string/split % #",") (clojure.string/split (clojure.string/replace (slurp "calendars.csv") #"\r" "") #"\n"))]
   (map download links))
```

I noticed `let` evaluation must be last or else it does not get evaluated. This is confusing to me.  Nonetheless when I implement this in a loop, `let` is never evaluated since I think recur ends up being inferred.

```
(while
(do
  (prn "sleeping for 60 seconds")
  (Thread/sleep 60000)
  (prn "kicking off calendar downloads @ " (new java.util.Date))
  (let [links (map #(clojure.string/split % #",") (clojure.string/split (clojure.string/replace (slurp "calendars.csv") #"\r" "") #"\n"))]
   (map download links))
  ))
```

I'd prefer for `sleep` to be at the end of this `do` section as well, but that is moot really.

How can I get `let` to evaluate? Does it have to do with my use of `map`? What am I misinterpreting here?

Download is a function:

```
(defn download [[calname ics]]
  (prn "attempting cal download: " calname)
  (try (spit (str dest calname ".csv") (slurp ics))
  (catch Exception e (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e)))))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert lazy sequence to non-lazy in Clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641626/how-to-convert-lazy-sequence-to-non-lazy-in-clojure)

Comment: this is not a duplicate, that only answers part of this question. (though it's tempting to make a tag for 'clojure-lazy-bug'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have been bitten by the lazy bug:

- *I noticed let evaluation must be last or else it does not get evaluated.*
  this is because the result of calling map is lazy so it is only evaluated if something reads the result. If you put it last, then it becomes the return value of the `do` which **gets printed by the repl**, which causes it to actually run.
- *when I implement this in a loop, let is never evaluated*:
  `while` will keep running until the return value of the expression is false. In this case the return **value of the expression is a lazy sequence that would cause some pages to be downloaded if anyone ever looked at it.** In this case nothing looks at the result so nothing is ever downloaded, and since it's not false it just keeps running.
- *How can I get let to evaluate?*:
  wrap the calls to map in `(doall (map ... ....))` to cause the lazy sequence to be evaluated.

Comment: Curious, would this function solve this dilemma, like a shorthand version for doall, or is it too simplistic and shortsighted for all scenarios? (defn dmap [f & [m]]
  (doall (map f m)))

Comment: yes that's the idea, though it needs an apply before the map to have the same function as map

Comment: on second thought I'm going to look at doall's source and sort of replicate it I think

Comment: (def dmap (comp doall map))

Answer (score 1):

My guess at what is happening:

`map` is a lazy function, so when it's the last item in the `do`, it is getting evaluated since that's what is being returned by the `do`. If it's not the last thing in the `do`, then its return value is not being used and so it's not getting evaluated.

[I ran into something similar myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046515/listbox-jlist-wont-update-dynamically-from-custom-listmodel).

**Try using `doseq` instead of `map`.**